# I am getting run time error '3061'

Tags: vba, insert

Need help!  Can't get my script below to work eventhough all the values are initialized as expected.  I am getting run time error '3061'.  Too few parameters. Expected 2.  When I copy and paste the same insert into Access SQL and replace the variables with values the query works.  So frustrating.  Please help!

```
Private Sub Clock_In_Click()

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim txEmployee_ID As Integer
    Dim txEmployee_Name As String
    Dim strSQL As String


    txEmployee_ID = Employee_ID.Value
    txEmployee_Name = First_Name.Value & " " & Last_Name.Value

    strSQL = " INSERT INTO " & _
    " Timesheet_tbl(Employee_ID,Employee,Timesheet_Date,Time_In) VALUES " & _
         "(txEmployee_ID,txEmployee_Name,Date(),Time());"

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Debug.Print strSQL

    dbs.Execute strSQL

    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

VALUES should not be in double quotes. you're passing a long string instead of each variable values. Note the single quotes enclosing txEmployee_Name variable (as string).

```
  strSQL = " INSERT INTO " & _
    " Timesheet_tbl(Employee_ID,Employee,Timesheet_Date,Time_In) VALUES " & _
         "(" & txEmployee_ID & ", '" & txEmployee_Name & "', " & Date & ", " & Time() & ");"
```